# How can I get the json data from an url?

Tags: json, cross-domain, jsonp, getjson

I'm looking forward to it for days.
I made a rest app. I send a string data to it via url and get response a json data from it.
When I write the url on browser I'm seeing the json value succesfuly:

the url:

http://mydomain.com:82/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/MEHMET?jsoncallback=?

returning json : {"result":["TEMHEM"]}

I'm triying getJSON like below

$.getJSON( "http://mydomain.com:82/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/MEHMET?jsoncallback=?", function( data) {
       var dt= JSON.stringify(data);
       console.log(dt[0].result);
 });

but it give an error :

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
:82/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/MEHMET?jsoncallback=jQuery17109582267256919295_1392369668825&_=1392369670613:1
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Some hints from my side:

You can double check your service with Firefox RestClient Plugin which supports also JSON.

Have a look at the http header for mime type also.

I have tested your code with the service url: http://ip.jsontest.com/ and the request was made without problem.

Another problem can be the console.log command:

Try to change this to something like

```
    console.log(data.result[0]);
```

or

```
    alert(data.result[0]);
```

To debug things I use Firebug (also a Firefox plugin).

Good luck.

Martin

Comment: Thanks for answer Martin. 
I've learned the cause of this problem. The reason is Same-origin policy
Regard..
Same-origin policy ==> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy